# StreamProvider in flutter: do not always change the UI but set when

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a `StreamProvider` as follows

```
Stream<List<Match>> streamMatches() =>
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('matches').snapshots()
    .map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => Match.fromJson(doc.data(), doc.id)).toList());

StreamProvider<List<Match>>(create: (context) => streamMatches(), initialData: [])
```

which I use it in a `ListView` inside a `StatelessWidget`

```
   ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: _getMatchesWidget(context.watch<List<Match>>())
```

This is nice because any update to the DB refreshes the stream. However I would like to not have the UI showing the list view change constantly in real-time for new updates (since I believe it might be a bad UX).

I would like to use a pull-on refresh (`RefreshIndicator`) and update the list view only `onRefresh`

Of course I also would like to update the list of matches in background when the user is not visualizing the list (e.g. he paused the app).

How can I tell the `StreamProvider` to update only in certain cases or what other `Provider` should I use for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this code below:

```dart
    context.watch<List<Match>>()
```

to this:

```dart
    context.read<List<Match>>()
```

`.read` returns the `List<Match>` object without listening to it while `.watch` makes the widget listen to changes on `List<Match>`

**Edit**:

When you want to update the `List<Match>` object, you can call `setState` which will rebuild the UI and read the latest value of the stream.

You mentioned that you want to refresh the list using the `RefreshIndicator`.

You can just add the setState to your `onRefresh` method like below:

```dart
    RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
       setState(() {
         //This refreshes the list
       });
    
      }
    )
```

Comment: Ok but that means that for the whole life of the application the list will never change and I don't want that

Comment: @alexlipa, please check out the latest answer. This should suffice for your use case.

Comment: I am using a `StatelessWidget` since I am using `Provider`. I will add it to the question

Comment: I'll advise updating the widget to a `StatefulWidget`. You don't have to use a `StatelessWidget` just because you're using `provider`. Here's an answer from `provider`'s creator, Rémi Rousselet, explaining  this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445408/11039164